# what Git Ignore field means in github desktop while creating a new repository

Tags: gitignore, github-desktop

see the  Git Ignore option in the below image.What I have to choose, I am creating an ionic-framework repository.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBvkd.png

Comment: So I think the deeper question is, if I am creating a repo using the UI in Git hub Desktop, and I use the popup menu for gitignore to choose (say) "Python", does that mean that I'm ignoring python? or does that mean that I'm *not* ignoring python? There's room for improvement in the UI since that's ambiguous...

Answer (score 2):

.gitignore is a file which, Git uses to determine which files and directories to ignore, before you make a commit. These files/directories will not be pushed into the repository.

If you have any files or directories that don't need to be pushed into the repository, then you can include them. (a simple example : log files)

Comment: thanks I know it.but I wanted to know that in github Deskop application what I have to choose from the dropdown list  containing language, framework . I didn't see any option of ionic or javascript . please help.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no ionic option, you can ignore it, and create it locally on your repo, then push it back to your GitHub repo.

To create it, see https://www.gitignore.io/api/ionic3

It does generate an Ionic `.gitignore` for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/installing-and-configuring-github-desktop/overview/creating-your-first-repository-using-github-desktop#creating-a-new-repository) of GitHub, it is the language you are using (hence the language of files that are NOT being ignored). It will create a .gitignore file with a lot of git ignore file types and folders. For example when you select Python from drop down-menu, the .gitignore file has around 150 lines containing commented names of automatically (by compiler, builder, etc.) created files/folders (such as **pycache**/|*.py[cod]|*$py.class|.Python|build/|develop-eggs/|dist/|downloads/|eggs/|.eggs/...).

It is worth to mention, that you need not to choose anything and manually create your own .gitignore file later.